# NodeJS destructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, destructor

The code:

```
function terminator(sig) 
{
  if (typeof sig === "string") 
  {
    console.log('Received %s - terminating Node server ...', sig);
    process.exit(1);
  };
  console.log('Node server stopped.');
};

process.on('exit', function() { terminator(); });

function terminatorSetup(element, index, array) 
{
  process.on(element, function() { terminator(element); });
};

['SIGHUP', 'SIGINT', 'SIGQUIT', 'SIGILL', 'SIGTRAP', 'SIGABRT', 'SIGBUS', 'SIGFPE', 'SIGUSR1', 'SIGSEGV', 'SIGUSR2', 'SIGPIPE', 'SIGTERM'].forEach(terminatorSetup);
```

Somehow this does not work on Windows, exiting with Ctrl+C doesn't print anything on the console, but when I insert a `console.log(element);` before `process.on(element, ...);` it works just fine. Am I missing anything? Nothing I use there should be async afaik.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows does not support signals](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events). As such, your signal handlers are never triggered and instead your `exit` handler is called. Since in that handler you call `terminator()` without any arguments, the check for `sig` being a string fails, thus nothing is printed.

Also note that calling `process.exit()` within the `exit` event is redundant - the process is about to exit and there is no stopping that. I understand that you wanted to use this logic for the signal handlers where the process is not required to exit in all cases, but since you cannot use signals on Windows...

Comment: Shouldn't it print `Node server stopped.` nontheless? Also, when I enter the console line it actually does print that SIGINT got fired.

Comment: Hmm, you are right, I missed that line. Nevertheless, signals are really not available on Windows natively - are you using Cygwin or some such posix environment emulation...?